# Can it be decided whether there exists a string accepted by a given NFA at least k ways?

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, undecidability

Can I think this way:

We can convert a NFA to a RE using GFA.

We build a series of GFAs. At each step, one state (other than start or accept) is removed and replaced by transitions that have the same effect.

So, if we can convert k REs which have different forms but accept same language, then there must exists a string that the NFA accepts along k paths.

Does that sound right?

How to prove it properly?

Comment: What's a GFA? Also, proof: if $w$ is your word, check all paths of length $|w|$ for whether they produce $w$. If at least two paths do, output "yes", otherwise "no".

Comment: Are you sure you only want decidability? As G. Bach says, it's essentially trivial - we can just enumerate all possibilities and check them.

Comment: @G.Bach As our instructor taught us, it is called "generalized FA", which means each transition is given by an RE.

Comment: @LukeMathieson Yes, just the decidability. I know it is not that hard to think it through, but as a green hand, I just don't know how to prove it in a proper way.

Comment: @G.Bach You are not given $w$! The question asks whether there *exists* a word $w$ which is accepted along two paths. Even if you are given $w$, you have to be slightly more careful since there could be infinitely many paths generating $w$. (Though in that case there are at least two...)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yeah I misread, and what I said only generalizes to semi-decidability without a specific word. For a fixed word, I don't really have to be careful since without $\epsilon$-transitions (which I assume aren't present since he said NFA, not $\epsilon$-NFA), there are only finitely many paths of a given length.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to use a construction very similar to the power set construction. In the usual power set construction, each NFA state has two possibilities: unreachable and reachable. In our case, each NFA state has three possibilities: unreachable, uniquely reachable, and multiply reachable. It is straightforward to carry out the construction, and I will not spell it out here. A state in the DFA is *accepting* if either it contains a multiply reachable NFA accepting state, or it contains at least two uniquely reachable NFA accepting states. There is a word accepted by the NFA using more than one path if the language of the new DFA is not empty. In fact, the language accepted by the DFA consists of all words accepted by more than one path.

Using the same idea, we can compute the language of words accepted by the NFA using exactly, at most, or at least $k$ paths.

Comment: This is delightfully rigorous! Thanks!

Comment: @ylorn You and I seem to have very different opinions of what "rigorous" means. It's certainly a nice idea, but no rigorous proof; you need to add the details of the construction, and a proof that it does the right thing.